# C++23: How to erase a subrange from vector

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I'm trying to erase a subrange returned by `find_if( vec | reverse | slide(width) )` from a `vector`, but I can't get their parameter types to match anyway.

I'm not sure if the iterator is invalidated in these pipes. I'd like to just use the existing subrange iterator to erase it instead of wasting performance to find it again. Is that possible?

---

Full code:
[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/n7q1fh57W)

Core function:

```cpp
std::vector<Data> take_last_successive_data(std::vector<Data> &target) {
    const auto &data_is_successive = [](const auto &data) { return data.is_successive; };

    auto windows = target | views::reverse | views::slide(2);
    auto result = ranges::find_if(
        windows,
        [&](const auto &window) {
            return ranges::all_of(window | views::take(window.size() - 1), data_is_successive);
        }
    );

    if (result == windows.end()) {
        std::cout << "not found\n";
        return {};
    } else {
        // How to erase subrange `result`
        target.erase();

        auto ret = to_vector(*result | views::reverse);
        for (const auto &data : ret) {
            std::cout << data.value << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, decompose `subrange` to get the pair of `reverse_iterator`, then call its `base()` to get the underlying iterator and pass it into `erase()`.

Note that the `erase()` must be performed after `ret` is created to ensure that the iterator points to a valid element.

```
} else {
    auto ret = to_vector(*result | views::reverse);
    for (const auto &data : ret) {
        std::cout << data.value << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // How to erase subrange `result`
    auto [rbegin, rend] = *result;
    target.erase(rend.base(), rbegin.base());
    
    return ret;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qWPK9T6E3)

Comment: It's very clean, and thanks for the note, I almost missed it.